# Android AlarmManager: repeating task stops working at some point

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager to force my Android widget update itself every hour regardless the phone is awake or sleeps.
Here the code (5-mins update interval set):

```
 @Override
public void onEnabled(final Context context) {
    startWidget(context);
}

private void startWidget(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 300000,
            getPendingSelfIntent(context, UPD_CLICKED));
}
```

I also have set Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

The problem is it never updates after an hour or more. More, if I set an interval to 2 or 5 mins it also stops at some point after several updates, after 5-10 successful updates! The phone seems to sleep during the tests.
What might be the reason for such the behavior?

Phone: Xiaomi MI5

SDK: 25

Comment: Does it start to work again after you wake up the device?

Comment: Nope! I had to re-enable my widget (delete it and then put on the screen again...) I feel that Android stops it for energy-saving reasons. Not sure.